# How far should you go with estimating your tasks?

Tags: project-management, project-planning, estimation, task

What is the good resolution of time to use for estimating duration of your tasks?

is it like 0.5, 1, 2, 5 days or should you go down to hours like 0.5, 1, 2, 4 hours and then continue up to days?

should a change to a label text be task at all? ( ETA < 1min )

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrum uses values of 0, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 20, 40 and 100. The time of the values is in hours, when you plan in finer detail (breaking down feature requests into technical tickets) and days, when you plan the bigger picture (big-picture features).

In general, if you estimate a ticket over 20 hours (or 20 days), your tasks should be split up into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it really depends. Personally, I like tasks to be smaller (should be estimated in hours, usually using the something close to Fibonacci series: 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ...).

About small tasks, usually they should be estimated too. Even minor changes require some work like creating tests, seeing if none of the other ones broke, sending to server, etc. You could create a 15 min in the series for stuff like these :)

Answer (score 2):

It's really hard to predict the future.

The units (minutes, hours, days, weeks, fortnights) don't matter.

Pick a unit that makes your manager happy.

Just be clear that an estimate of 30 minutes, .5 hour or .0625 days is only a guess, not a fact.

An estimate of 0.0625 days or 30 minutes looks really precise because it has a lot of decimal places.  However, any ambiguity about the requirements, the architecture, the language, the libraries, the unit tests, or anything else will make this number incorrect.

The very best you can hope for is that the average of all your estimates is reasonably close to the actual facts as they unfold.  This means that half your estimates will be too low and half will be too high.  It also means that some fraction of your estimates will be really, really far from your manager's hoped-for accuracy.

Comment: Unfortunately there are 1,000 ways to lose a day and approximately zero ways to gain a day. So the half over/under rule doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, losing and gaining a day at a time don't lead to the errors in estimating.  Everything leads to errors in estimating.  Every single thing about the future is unknowable.  If you're a good guesser, your guesses are in the middle of the future outcomes.  About half the time things will be more than you guessed.  The rest of the time, they'll be less than you guessed.  Day-by-day gains and losses aren't the cause of estimating errors.  Everything is the cause of errors.

Comment: Multiple studies (and practical experience) show that estimates tend to be optimistic. Here's a link to one such study: http://psiexp.ss.uci.edu/research/teaching/Tversky_Kahneman_1974.pdf. A quote from that study: "The general tendency to overestimate the probability of conjunctive events leads to unwarranted optimism in the evaluation of the likelihood that a plan will succeed or that a project will be completed on time." Also see Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planning_fallacy

Comment: @RoadWarrior: While possibly true, that's not the point.  "The very best you can hope for is... half your estimates will be too low and half will be too high."  While mere mortals may be optimistic on average, the very best you can hope for is to be wrong only half the time.

Comment: You can hope for that, but it won't happen :-)

Answer (score 1):

Planning and estimating time required is never the goal of your project, so those units must serve some purpose.

The good rule to use is this: split the task into smaller chunks, until you know **exactly** what you should do next (and it is not planning). This "knowing exactly what to do" thing is a little subjective, but tasks longer than 2 days rarely fit into this category.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how accurate you want to be.

I personally use minutes as "days" or "months" can be misleading time periods. For example if you say something will take 1 day - does that mean 24 hours solid work? Or 8 hours? Or the average 3-4 hours of productivity within a working day?

All tasks should be listed, but if they are small you can often group them. But remember that just because it's only changing a label text there is more time involved that just changing the label, you have to find it, open the file, make the change, commit the changes, update any documentation, test it etc - so tasks very rarely only take less than 1 minute.

Also try to put an upper limit on the task time. If your adding tasks that are taking over 3-4 hours, break them down into smaller sub-tasks and list those. This will give you a much more accurate estimate.

Answer (score 0):

I have found myself sorting tasks into these categories:

- Half a day
- Whole day
- Whole week
- Several weeks

In my work environment where we do a lot of second-level support, it doesn't make sense to have a more granular system. It is also good to have some slack in the planning, so that you can take an hour to make small improvements to your work environment.

Comment: don't you think that "several weeks" should be divided into smaller chunks ?

Comment: I agree, estimating several weeks/ 100+ hours is definitely an indication that further planning is needed. In my environment, I use this as a "here be dragons" estimation to communicate that the problem isn't clearly stated or that the desired solution is not yet fully understood.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use units of hours should they be appropriate (1h, 4.5h, 6h, etc).  Once days creep into the equation then I tend to not use hours and keep days as the only unit being used (3d, 7d, 10d).  Overestimating slightly gives room to accommodate those undesired but expected complications you will hit along the way.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between est. work effort  - how long something should take to complete -  and est. when something will be done (aka duration) - when that something is expected to get completed based on other tasks.

You can never predict the future and any est. is just that - an est. - the likelihood of being able to predict 1 week out in 1/2 hour increments isn't that great, what if the first 6 tasks take 5 min. more to complete, you're 1/2 off (after 3 hours of work).

I would suggest creating a work breakdown structure (WBS) to determine effort and then group the tasks into no less then day groupings and no more then week groupings (depending on the overall duration of the project - you never want to have an increment representing more then 2-3% of overall work effort).  This will allow programs to switch between tasks (normal working conditions) without the pressure of having to meet a specific 1/2 hour delivery.